# I need to increment an IP address within a given range using Perl

Tags: perl

For example

```
 my $starting_ip = '1.2.3.4';
 my $ending_ip   = '1.3.0.5';
```

my output will be

```
 1.2.3
 1.2.4
 1.2.5
 ..
 ..
 1.2.255
 1.3.0
```

I tried so far:

```
use Socket;

my $startIp        = $ARGV[0];
my $endIp          = $ARGV[1];
my $start_address  = unpack 'N', inet_aton( $startIp );
my $finish_address = unpack 'N', inet_aton( $endIp );
my @f              = split( '\.', $endIp );
my $last_ip        = join( '.', $f[0], $f[1], $f[2] );

for ( my $address = $start_address;
        $address <= $finish_address;
        $address = $‌​address + 255 ) {

    my $new_ip = inet_ntoa( pack 'N', $address );
    my @a = split( '\.', $new_ip );

    $new_ip = join( '.', $a[0], $a[1], $a[2] );

    print "$new_ip\n";
}

print "$last_ip\n";
```

There is no need to consider the last portion of the IP address.

Comment: Have you looking into `for` loops. Maybe even, nested `for` loops? What have you tried?

Comment: _No need to consider_ about what you have tried

Comment: Please don't post your code in the comments, edit it into the question.

Comment: @ssr1012: `perl` is no more correct than `PERL`.

Comment: @ssr1012 see the comment on my edit.

Comment: @ssr1012 `Perl` is the name of the language, and `perl` the interpreter. `PERL` would make it an acronym, which `Perl` isn't.

Comment: Hint: [Convert IP address to integer](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=786521) (and reverse)

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```
sub ip_addr { $_[0] = pack "N", 1 + unpack "N", $_[0] }
my $starting_ip = 1.2.4.4;
my $ending_ip = 1.3.0.5;
   for ( $addresses = $starting_ip; $addresses le $ending_ip; ip_addr($addresses) ) {
      printf "%vd\n", $addresses;
   }
```

Though there are many other ways, I think an even better option would be to use [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/~manu/Net-IP-1.26/IP.pm)